# Backup db scheme (structure) easily

Tags: sql, postgresql, backup, postgresql-9.2

I have a pretty big db in the terms of amount of different db object, not the size. I want to backup it (its structure, scheme). Preferably, I'd like to get the sql code. Of course, I can navigate to each its object and just get it but, as I said, there are a lot of them.

How do I do this easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pg_dump --schema-only --format=plain > dump_file.sql` to dump your schema (db objects without data) into a sql file.

Details here: [`pg_dump`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html).